# Setting imeOptions inside AutoCompleteTextView crashes app

Tags: android

I am trying to add a done button to the Keyboard, so when the user finishes writing, he can close the keyboard without pressing the back Button.

However the trouble is, I am using an `AutoCompleteTextView` which is inside a `CardView` . So I am unable to set `imeOptions` 
Here is my Code :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_below="@id/home_image"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:elevation="7dp"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Hey, where are you?"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the question is, how do I enable a done Button in this case to close the Keyboard when done typing?

Comment: why don't you try setting imeOption inside code  AutoCompleteTextView (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.info_text).setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Replace this line android:imeOptions="actionDone" instead of         android:imeOptions="actionDone

Answer (score 1):

i guess you need to add `android:singleLine="true"` for imeoptions="actionDone" to work..
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:singleLine="true"` to a `AutoCompleteTextView`. If it is convenient for you.